# can i add my own option for git add --patch?

Tags: git, line-endings

i wonder - is it possible to add my own option for the `git add --patch` prompt?

Background:

I am currently working on a project, that has initially been written on a windows machine but is now maintained in my unix environment. When opening files in PHPStorm and changing some lines PHPStorm (and other IDEs/Editors as well) will convert all DOS lineendings to UNIX lineendings. So the diff git shows me contains the whole file.

I will have to cancel the patch process and run `unix2dos` on the file first, then make `git add --patch` again.

It would really be very convenient to be able to simply hit "u" or some other key to convert a file from unix to dos line-endings on the fly.

I know - alternatively i could configure my IDEs to not change line endings or i could convert all dos line-endings to unix line-endings in one commit and be done with it but i would prefer this flexible solution.

Does anyone know how - can i add my own "hook" for `git add --patch`?

Comment: The `--patch` mode of `git add` is actually a Perl program, located in the "exec path" for Git: run `git --exec-path` to see what that exec path is. You can replace that Perl program with your own code (or edit it in place); just remember that updating Git is likely to re-install the original.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a `pre-commit` hook to do the conversion for you... but then it would run on all commits so that might not be what you want. More info here: https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks